# Sci Fi Novel: expedition to the arctic where they found giant (alien?) gods in search for humanity's origin. (not Mountains of Madness)

Tags: story-identification

I forgot the title of this book as I saw this in a Facebook link from Cracked. I forgot the topic of the link (something about movies and some similarities with some novels' plot). With this one novel's plot a bit akin to that of the movie Prometheus, where there's an expedition in search of the species' origins except they never left the planet. The thumbnail showed the book's cover or some art of it. Two or three explorers  staring into the snowy distance where a kneeling giant white being was located between two snowy mountains.

I got into Calling of Cthulhu recently and was trying to find other books in the same genre. Then I remembered this one but forgot the title. And I searched Mountains of Madness and its not the same book as the one I'm describing (with the similarity of ancient and possibly alien beings and a journey to the north).

Ps Thanks for the Help!

Comment: When did you see the thing from Cracked?

Comment: I've read that John Taine's "The Greatest Adventure" (1929) is remarkably similar to At the Mountains of Madness, but I can't find an edition of it with a cover that matches your description.

Comment: This cover does feature explorers, mountains, and giant beings, but the scene and composition don't match what you remember. http://www.lwcurrey.com/pages/books/147298/john-taine-eric-temple-bell/the-greatest-adventure

Comment: Thanks for all the reply! It was probably 2 or 3 years ago when a link from Cracked was shared in my FB page. I'll try out The Greatest Adventure. Again thank you.